# Returning autoreleased objects using ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

Assuming that I wrote the code below in a class A:

```
-(NSArray *) returnListNames {

    NSArray *returnList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:myListNames];

    return (returnList);
}
```

And in a class B I get that list in some scope in this way:

```
{
    /* Without ARC I would  retain the array returned from ClassA 
       to guarantee its reference like this:
       [[myClassA returnListNames] retain]; */

    NSArray *myNames = [myClassA returnListNames];  

}
```

Considering that the `returnList` was allocated using an autorelease method, how can I guarantee that I won't lose the reference to it using ARC (under which I can't use `retain`)?
Will I have to use `[[NSArray alloc] init]` on the `myNames` array? Or I must use `alloc` on `returnList` instead of an autorelease method? Or can I just rely on ARC? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ARC will handle this for you, so you can just rely on it and go about your business with that array. If it sees that you need to retain `myNames`, it will add a retain call for you for example, or do whatever else it actually does when you compile the code that uses it.

Comment: So I can continue to use an autorelease method on allocating the *returnList that ARC will guarantee it's existence. Right?

Comment: That's right. It doesn't even matter whether you use an autorelease method or an alloc-init.

Comment: @BoltClock when the object is released in this case?